# Digital or analogue filtering?

Tags: filters, digital-filters, analog, butterworth

I'm trying to self learn the art of signal processing whilst moving through my third year pure maths degree.

Sorry if my terminology is incorrect however I hope I am understandable!

I am looking at data which is coming from an accelerometer, distance data from a separate sensor and time data incrementing by 0.01 seconds e.g. to be clear in case my terminology is incorrect I have a dataset which has a row for each 0.01 seconds with the row having data from the accelerometer and distance sensors. I believe this means the data is sampled at 100 Hz.

Please can someone confirm that my choice of using a digital filter is correct?

My reasoning is that the data is not analogue and is digital and as such I should not use a standard Butterworth (or other) filter and should look for a digital version. Is this reasoning correct?

I want to use the data to compare the second derivative with respect to time of the distance with the RSS of acceleration and before I do this I want to 'clean' up the data as much as possible and it is my understanding that filtering will give me this.

I am using Octave to perform the maths and have various pieces of code to filter the data, however I do not feel like I understand the filter settings I should use! Before I start to try and understand the filter settings are all my assumptions and reasoning reasonable?

My Octave code for my filter is as follows:

```
%I use Octave, however I believe Matlab will be very similar if not identical

% I believe that my sample frequency is 100 Hz.
mysamf = 100;

% Nyquist frequency. I believe this is set to half the sample frequency
Fnyq = mysamf/2;

% I do not understand the cut-off frequency, however I set it to 45
% I can see through plotting the results that it does make an impact.
mycutf=45;

% Here I create a 1st order Butterworth filter, using the above restrictions.
[b,a]=butter(2, mycutf/Fnyq);

% I pass my dataset that contains the displacements.
output=filter(b,a,v_dist);
```

Edit:

I realize I should have explained this at the beginning however I didn't think that the source of the data would influence the filtering approach (digital/analogue).

My Sensor data is coming from a Pogo stick - the acceleometer mounted at the base of the stick and a displacement sensor measuring the movement of the stick and spring assembly.

The Pogo stick is being used by a Gazelle on steroids so is going wild, however is always bouncing around on and off axis, big jumps small hops, soft ground hard ground.

Thanks,

Sam.

Comment: Hi!. It seems you are on the right track. Can you put some code, so that we could help...

Comment: Before filtering, it is convenient to explore your data set and estimate how much noise it really has. If the data is very clean, you may not need a filter at all.

Comment: you have 2 related inputs that are from a physical object, while a bit beyond simple filtering, a Kalman Filter would probably be most appropriate for the data you describe

Comment: @MBaz This is a really good point. Is there a way that I can test if a filter is required?

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz That's really interesting you said that, I had stumbled across this filter whilst reading around the topic. Do you know if Octave has an easy pathway to implement a Kalman Filter? I've read a couple of nice walkthroughs of how a Kalman Filter works however I'm struggling to implement it.

Comment: @SamilHorper The typical approach is to do it in the frequency domain: you make a model for how the data should look like, then how it actually looks like, then remove the difference with a filter (I'm oversimplifying but hopefully you get the idea). You can also do some sort of enveloping/averaging to remove spikes (even if they're not actually "noise"), plenty of related questions on this site. And as Stanley suggested, you can use a Kalman filter to reduce the uncertainty in your measurements.

Comment: The hard part of a kalman filter is getting the correct state variable equations. the Unscented Kalman Filter is somewhat easier. Google and you shall find

Comment: `My reasoning is that the data is not analogue and is digital and as such I should not use a standard Butterworth (or other) filter and should look for a digital version. Is this reasoning correct?` Yes.  The reason matlab/scipy have analog filter design functions is to generate the values for an electronic filter or simulate one, etc.  It's not for use with `filter` command.

Comment: @endolith are you saying that my use of the filter command is incorrect? My understanding is that I first define the parameters of the Butterworth filter and I then pass my displacement data through the filter using coefficients calculated from the Butterworth.

Comment: @SamilHorper No I think it's correct

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz When I read about Kalman filtering I get the distinct impression that it is about prediction, however in this scenario, prediction does not seem to be my goal since the Pogo stick could be reversing direction randomly. Have I misunderstood Kalman filtering? My goal was to filter my sensor data so that I could compare accelerometer to displacements to better understand their relationship.

Comment: @SamilHorper I made a suggestion that I thought would be constructive. beyond that I am indifferent